# Trim End of a UNC path to a backslash and then add to a list

Tags: c#, string

Let me start of by saying that my C# is pretty bad.  I am working on a tool for my job (I hope others could find it useful too) that will create security groups in AD based on a provided file path from an SMB share, assign appropriate permissions on the directory (last folder in the file path), and then give the groups list permissions to each parent folder above it so users can navigate to the directory while not seeing other directories they have not been given access to (we use access based enumeration on our file servers, so they will not see any other folders unless they already have access to them by another security group, etc...).  I have the first two parts working.  So, right now the program creates the needed security groups in AD and assigns them the correct permissions on the directory for the path provided (\fileserver\some\example\shareddirectory).

What I think I need to do is basically make a list that will contain a path for each of the parent folders for the directory then use a foreach loop to assign the list permissions on the ACLs of each directory.  So, using the example above, the list would include the following:

\\fileserver\some

\\fileserver\some\example

The number of parent folders can vary, so the number of items in the list could vary too.

First question: is making a list and then using a foreach loop a good way to do this or is there a better way?

Second question:  how would I do this?  So far, I have learned that dealing with backslashes is tricky because they are escape characters.  I basically got stuck on trimming the string to remove the last backslash and the characters that follow it from the string before adding it to the list and how to do this recursively till there is nothing left to trim.

Thanks!

Comment: Unless you've got a pretty weirdly built security setup, they shouldn't *need* permissions on parent directories, provided they use the complete path to the directory to access it. (By default, everyone gets the "Bypass Traverse Checking" privilege)

Comment: @ragenkagen: Please leave a comment whether my answer was helpful. Thank you!

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever:  thanks for the comment.  Users will have to be able to navigate to the path, so unfortunately it is necessary in our environment.

Comment: @MareInfinitus Thanks! Sorry, I did not get to look at this till tonight. This definitely worked to get the list I was looking for. I really appreciate the help! Now I am stuck at assigning the permissions on the paths represented by the strings in the list. I am using the same approach that works to assign permissions on the full path itself, but it is not working in the foreach loop I created. I am using the approach outlined here: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163885.aspx

Comment: hmmm...link didn't work above, here it is: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163885.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like the following

```
class DirectoryHelper
{
    public List<string> GetDirectories(string path)
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
        {
            if (path.Last() != '\\')
            {
                path += "\\";
            }

            EnumerateDictories(list, path);
        }

        return list;
    }

    private void EnumerateDictories(IList<string> results, string path)
    {
        var parent = Directory.GetParent(path);

        if (parent != null)
        {
            EnumerateDictories(results, parent.FullName);

            results.Add(parent.FullName);
        }
    }
}
```

This is called like:

```
DirectoryHelper helper = new DirectoryHelper();
var dir = helper.GetDirectories(@"C:\Temp\Folder1\");
```

You have to add some code to protect against invalid directory strings I believe,
but you probably get the idea.

-update-
have edited some backslash handling, so that you do not have to care for it.